# In WPF Styling: How does ItemsPanel find what to replace off the Template (in an ItemsControl)

Tags: wpf, xaml

this is a more less in depth technical question of how things acutally work. And a suspicion:

```
...
  <ListBox Style="{StaticResource lbs}"/>
...
```

Consider you have a ListBox somewhere in you GUI and you want to style it with a custom panel (SophisticatedGridPanel). Suppose I have created this style which is regarding "Template" quite close to what the actual default is: [msdn styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (anyways simplified)

```
   <Style x:Key="lbs">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" Background="Blue">
                        <StackPanel Margin="2" IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>    
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SeriesToDisplay}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <local:SophisticatedGridPanel GridLineColor="Gray" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
      <Setter.Value>
        ...bla...
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

So we set `Template` (but with StackPanel) and `ItemsPanel`.

Now: How does the WPF styling system go to work and (how) will it replace the `StackPanel` by the `SophisticatedGridPanel` ?

I suspect it is the Set Property `IsItemsHost="True"`  on the Template's `StackPanel` which makes the indicator. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, the StackPanel will not be replaced by the SophisticatedGridPanel because the StackPanel is hardcoded in the template, as an items host.

If you replace the StackPanel by an

`<ItemsPresenter Margin="2"/>`

only then the set ItemsPanel will be used as an item host.

Comment: Well, you are right. This actually also works. But then I wonder why MS has in the abovenamed style defaults website a <StackPanel> inside but no <ItemsPresenter> °!°

Comment: @Robetto The MSDN website is misleading. It shows a ControlTemplate _example_, not the actual default style/template. If you take a look at the real default style (ex. in the Designer, choose "Edit template"), it does define an ItemsPresenter, with the name "ItemsPresenter".